# snap GPS points to sidewalks

Tags: arcgis-10.0, gps

I have whole bunch of GPS coordinates collected from a device and sometimes they shift around 10m. Is there anyway to filter/modify points and snap them to sidewalks? So far I've written some javascripts to map those points to the center line of the nearest driving path but I still want them to be on sidewalks.

I noticed ArcGIS can display street curbs. Is there any way to extract the curbs? I cannot finde APIs for curbs at all.

There are some questions on this site regarding making sidewalk maps but no real solutions are available yet. I would prefer utilizing existing data sets like shape file and curbs to map points instead of adding sidewalks on google maps manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ETGeoWizards.  The tool you are looking for is Global Snap Point (its in the Point section of the tool).  You could also look at Geospatial Modeling Environment from SpatialEcology.com.  They have a tool called snappoints.

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help